# Making a tree shape.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to print something that looks like this:

```
    * 
   *** 
  ***** 
 ******* 
********* 
   *** 
   *** 
   ***
```

with the user inputting the width of the thickest part of the head and the width of the stem.

So far I have managed to get the head to print using this code:

```
def head(size):
    n=1
    while n < size+1:
        astri = n * "*"
        print '{:^50}'.format(astri)
        n += 2

 print head(x)

x = input("Please enter an odd integer for the head")
```

But I'm completely stuck on how to do the stem of the tree.

Comment: Your post is missing a question. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I'm stuck on how to include the tree trunk. The code I have posted does the top triangle, but I also need to be able to include the trunk.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that in the post. But neither the original post nor your comment include a question. In future, you'll receive higher-quality answers if you actually ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def tree(head, stem):
    #for head
    for i in xrange(1, head+1, 2):
        print '{:^{}}'.format('*'*i, head)
    #for trunk
    for _ in xrange(3):
        print '{:^{}}'.format('*'*stem, head)
...         
>>> tree(10, 3)
    *     
   ***    
  *****   
 *******  
********* 
   ***    
   ***    
   ***    
>>> tree(5, 1)
  *  
 *** 
*****
  *  
  *  
  *
```

---

**Update:**

To keep the width of `stem` in proportion to width of `head`:

```
def tree(head, stem):
    for i in xrange(1, head+1, 2):
        print ('*'*i).center(head)
    x = (head/2) if (head/2)%2 else (head/2)-1
    for _ in xrange(stem):
        print ('*'*x).center(head)

>>> tree(12, 2)
     *      
    ***     
   *****    
  *******   
 *********  
*********** 
   *****    
   *****    
>>> tree(14, 4)
      *       
     ***      
    *****     
   *******    
  *********   
 ***********  
************* 
   *******    
   *******    
   *******    
   *******
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think when I posted the question I didn't make it clear but I wanted the trunk to be the same width everytime but be able to change it's length. I've tried to do this myself, and decided that the width should always be the width of the head divided by 2, but I can't work out how to actually implement it. Can you help?

Comment: @JaAnTr And what about height of `stem`?

Comment: @hcwhsa that's almost fixed it! The width of the stem is now in proportion to the width of the head, but the length of the stem is always 3, I can't see why this is though.

Comment: @hcwsha don't worry, I realised it's because of the xrange(3).

Comment: @JaAnTr To keep the stem in proportion to the width of the stem, try to round to the closest odd number. Something like: `x = math.ceil(head/2.) - (not head%2)`;`print '{:^{}}'.format('*'*int(x), head)`

Comment: +1. But you could use `str.center('*'*i, head)` which is easier to understand as well as shorter.